# .repsonseText returns empty string

Tags: php, google-chrome, responsetext

I'm getting the following error in Chrome:

**XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'http://localhost/getuser.php?q=1&sid=0.03709745453670621'. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.**

When I click on the link '*http://localhost/getuser.php?q=1&sid=0.03709745453670621*'. It displays the correct data but I don't understand why I keep getting this error and I can't figure out how to --allow-file-access-from-files.

When I run it in Firefox, I get no error but data isn't displayed either.
In Javascript code, **alert(xmlHttp.responseText)** shows nothing which is because the responseText contains empty String. Why doesn't it contain array data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue came up because of the same-origin policy. Adding **header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *')**; on top of my php file helped resolved the issue.